# rails data field json, populate it from more form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have table/model of projects and for each project I want to create table/model rewards. I don't know if one project will have 1 or 10 rewards so I thought that best might be to store it in one json data object to avoid creating fields in table like name1, name2, nameX.
The question is how can I have more form fields  and on submiting merge them and put in json data object?
Or is there any other way how to do that and I am missing that?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the backend you need to have two tables: projects and rewards. On the client side have a look at nested forms: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132

Browser will automatically take hierarchical form data, serialize and send to server. Rails will then save the data in your models.

Here's a tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1